# OnChange Event working fine browser in pc but not working on ipad

Tags: ipad, browser, onchange

onChange method working fine on pc browser but it is not working on ipad on browser it works perfect but not on ipad

Answer (score 0):

This issue also exists on Android tablets. Convert the onChange method to onClick and it should work.